# Apex Batch and PMD rule EmptyStatementBlock

Tags: apex, pmd

Does anyone know is there any option how to fix this PMD rule:

`EmptyStatementBlock`

in case when the error/violations/rule is reported for:

```
global override void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) { }
```

I am pretty new in Salesforce so I am afraid to add or change some things related to batch because of possible code breaking.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following annotation to your code:

```
@SuppressWarnings('PMD.EmptyStatementBlock')
```

Example:

```
@SuppressWarnings('PMD.EmptyStatementBlock')
public override void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) { }
```

This will disable the warning only for that method.

Note that `public` should generally be used for interface methods, unless you're making a Managed Package that needs this method to be global. Very few classes need `global`, and should not be marked as such unless necessary (e.g. WebService methods, @RemoteAction methods for iframe Visualforce pages, etc).

Comment: Worth noting that `global` is almost certainly the wrong access modifier to use here.

Comment: Thanks for replying but unfortunately I should not use @SuppressWarnings (to disable the warning) in my case.

Comment: @AdrianLarson True enough. Edited.

Comment: @mhdev And, why not?

Comment: @sfdcfox That's what I was told (avoid anything with @SuppressWarnings), or to try to find another solution in that case.

Comment: @mhdev Told by whom? There are legitimate use cases for this annotation; it's an explicit mention that you know the method is empty, and you don't want the warning. If you really don't want to use it, you could put anything else in there, like `Integer x = 0`, but then you have to explain why you're using useless code. Suppressing one specific warning makes it explicit that you are aware of the problem, but there's no other "good" fix for it. You wouldn't want to, for example, disable this globally in your project.

Comment: Can I add for example System.debug('Batch executed') into a curly braces? Something like this
`global override void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) { System.debug('Batch executed')}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128626/discussion-between-mhdev-and-sfdcfox).

Comment: @mhdev It's your code, you can do as you like, though if I were code reviewing you, I'd tell you to then remove the debug statements. They shouldn't be in production code.